# I want go find the Part no of this PWM controller

Tags: pwm

I want to know the part no of PWM controller. In upper side it is written 53T0 and in lower SZAB has been written. Please help me to find this.

Comment: Show a picture; knowing the package will help.

Comment: Vikas Sharma - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the rules here differ from typical forums. (b) Here are the [Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710). Please follow those as closely as possible e.g. [edit] your question to add a close-up photo of the device, as already mentioned, and also a photo showing the surrounding components so we can see where other relevant components, power tracks etc. are connected to that device. (c) Please add into the question how you know it's a PWM controller, not anything else.